# Advanced Settings dialog box on Ubuntu MATE is too long for the screen, so can't change settings

Tags: settings, mate, ubuntu-mate

When I click on **Advanced Settings** in **User Settings** in Ubuntu MATE, the diaog box is so long that it cannot fit the screen, so I cannot apply the settings, and I cannot resize the dialog box.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Either...

Hold down the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key, and then left-click-hold-drag inside the window and drag the window such that you can get to the Apply button.

Make sure that workspaces are enabled with 2-4 workspaces, open the settings, and then switch to workspace 2/3 to be able to get to the Apply button.

Comment: what's the point of the comment you left on the OP? As you know, the OP already receives a notification in their inbox when you post an answer. Adding a comment on top of that is just noise. Please don't do this. And don't badger people to accept your answer. And certainly not minutes after posting it.